# GoClipse Installation Error

Tags: eclipse, goclipse

I can not install GoClipse on Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

This is the error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: GoClipse 0.16.1.v201607061938 (goclipse_feature.feature.group 0.16.1.v201607061938)
  Missing requirement: GDB DSF Debugger Integration Core 5.0.0.201606062011 (org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb 5.0.0.201606062011) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.launchbar.core 2.0.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: GDB DSF Debugger Integration Core 5.0.0.201607151550 (org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb 5.0.0.201607151550) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.launchbar.core 2.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: GoClipse Eclipse Debug 0.16.1.v201607061938 (com.googlecode.goclipse.debug 0.16.1.v201607061938)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb [5.0.0,6.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: GoClipse 0.16.1.v201607061938 (goclipse_feature.feature.group 0.16.1.v201607061938)
    To: com.googlecode.goclipse.debug [0.16.1.v201607061938]
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Try formatting your question better.  I would try, but I cannot really tell what is what.

Comment: I'm trying install GoClipse on my Eclipse IDE.

Comment: I'm trying to install GoClipse on my Eclipse IDE. The Eclipse version is Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).  I followed the [GoClipse installation instructions]([https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/blob/latest/documentation/Installation.md#installation), i.e. I used the [goclipse update site]( http://goclipse.github.io/releases/ )  and selected **GoClipse**..  But the install is failing because it can not satisfy its dependencies as described in the error message above.     

What do I need to do so that the install will be successful?

Comment: Latest Goclipse version requires "Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) or later" https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/blob/latest/documentation/Installation.md#installation-requirements

Answer (score 0):

First install CDT(a c/c++ plugin) from marketplace and then try to install goclipse. I had the same issue, It worked for me.